# Insert an image to the left of a certain style in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

[How] Can I make a paragraph style that will insert an image to the side of a paragraph?

I have a certain paragraph style. I want Word to insert a small image to the left of that text (or, ideally, on the inner side of a mirror-margined page).

Edit: I am also open to possibilities other than paragraph styles -- the main point is that I do not want to add and position the images manually.

Think of the little exclamation marks or information signs of "... for Dummies" books, or have a look the little i, ball of wool and ladder in the image below.

[image]

Comment: And the question is .....?

Comment: @Xavierjazz The question is "How can I make a paragraph style that inserts an image to the side of the styled paragraph?"

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it can be done using the Style mechanism. Using picture bullets is probably the closest mechanism, but it doesn't really work well even if you break the bullets out into a 2-column table layout (which doesn't play well with the "inner side" thing). If it doesn't have to be a style-based solution, can you modify your question to allow other possibilities?

Comment: Editing the post to include the question would solve this.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the following lines. (I don't particularly like using tables in Word when what you want is ordinary text, particularly if it has to be usable by anyone, but the alternatives seem worse).

You have a 3-column table. The first column's right side is aligned with your document's left margin. The third column's left side is aligned with your document's right margin. You select columns 1 and 3 and make the vertical alignment so it's in the middle of the cell.

Each cell in the middle column contains a chunk of text. Where you want an image to one side, the image should be vertically aligned with the middle of that text.

At the top of your document you create a SET field for each image that you want to use. Say,

```
{ SET ball "<insert the image of the ball (or whatever it is) here, and resize it" 
}{ SET ladder "<insert the image of the ladder (or whatever it is) here, and resize it" }
```

(The {  } are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word)

For each chunk were you want an image (say, the ball), you insert the following nested field codes in the cell on one side:

```
{ IF { =int({ PAGE \#0 })/2)-({ PAGE \#0 }/2) } = 0 "{ ball }" }
```

and on the other side,

```
{ IF { =int({ PAGE \#0 })/2)-({ PAGE \#0 }/2) } <> 0 "{ ball }" }
```

*All* the  {  } are those special field braces.

Then select all the text press F9 to update all the fields. You will need to do that each time a chunk moves from one page to another (for example) because fields do not auto-update.

Some notes...

{ PAGE #0 } should return the numeric value of the page number, even if your page numbers are A, B, C or chapter-page numbers. But I am not sure that is quite enough to deal with all even/odd/two-sided scenarios.

It may be possible to simplify the field coding in various ways. I haven't really given it much thought.